# What does it mean *I next to a number in python?

Tags: python, precision

[image]

These numbers come from computing the arcsine, and I guess the *I is something to do with floating point precision in python. But cannot find anywhere what does it mean exactly.

Also, is there a straight forward way just keep the first number (i.e. before the - sign)? I mean without processing it as a string but rather some direct call to a method.

Comment: The *I components are imaginary values.

Comment: but numpy real doesn't seem to work there

Comment: Use abs(variable) to get the real component.

Comment: See the documents e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html

Comment: Those are [*complex numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

Comment: brilliant, thanks. But I still don't understand why the different representations (1j or *I)

Comment: @user96233: with what function did you calculate these? Can you provide a MWE to generate such number?

Comment: ah one is numpy and the other is simpy...thanks all!

Comment: @user96233: hmm... if I use this in `numpy`, I get `1+3j`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but with simpy you get *I

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `real` property of a complex number to isolate the real part.

```
>>> c = 1.57+1.60j
>>> c.real
1.57
```

The syntax for literal imaginary numbers in python is to use `j` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

> These numbers come from computing the arcsine, and I guess the *I is something to do with floating point precision in python. But cannot find anywhere what does it mean exactly.

**No**, these are [*complex numbers* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). Complex numbers contain a component with the square root of a *negative* number (mathematically speaking, this is a bit an "oversimplified explanation", so I recommend the Wikipedia article if you are interested in a more formal definition). This √(-1) is represented by a *i* (or sometimes *j*) in mathematics.

In Python itself, the number is represented with a `j`, like:

```
>>> 3+3j
(3+3j)
```

> is there a straight forward way just keep the first number

**Yes**, but the question is if that is a good idea. Simply ignoring the *imaginary* part is frequently not a good idea, since *1+2i* is *not* equivalent to *1*.

But if it is a vanilla Python complex number, you can use the `.real` attribute:

```
>>> (1+3j).real
1.0
```

This also works for `int`s, `float`s, etc. since it is not always possible to know in advance what the type of the result of a calculation will be.

In a similar way, you can obtain the value of the *imaginary* part:

```
>>> (1+3j).imag
3.0
```

In `numpy` there are similar functions to transform an array of complex numbers to their *real* or *imaginary* projection:

```
>>> arr
array([[ -5. -2.j,   8.+16.j, -16. +5.j,  -4. +7.j],
       [-19. +2.j,   1. +7.j,  -1.-14.j,  10. +6.j],
       [  8. -8.j, -12. -1.j,  22. +7.j, -10.-11.j]])
>>> np.real(arr)
array([[ -5.,   8., -16.,  -4.],
       [-19.,   1.,  -1.,  10.],
       [  8., -12.,  22., -10.]])
```